# Check and Change TwiMl for Twilio Client from <Start> to <Connect> on the fly

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

In my Twilio console, I have this Twiml for a phone number

```
<Response>  
      <Connect>
          <Stream url="wss://123-123-123.ngrok-free.app/ws"></Stream>
      </Connect>
</Response>
```

When a call comes into that number I want to check for specific parameters and based on that I want to change it to `Start` or vice versa

```
<Response>  
      <Start>
          <Stream url="wss://123-123-123.ngrok-free.app/ws"></Stream>
      </Start>
</Response>
```

From the approach I'm thinking, these should be the steps

1. What's the existing `Response` object or TwiML configuration so I can extract the `Stream Url`
2. Then update the TwiMl with the appropriate Stream of Connect Tag using this code

   await self.twilio_client.calls(self.call_sid).update_async(
   method="POST", twiml=response.to_xml()
   )

My question is mainly on Point 1. Also, will this approach work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a new webhook which is an HTTP post call and the response of that call is a VoiceResponse XML which was conditional

here is the sample code for that

```
def call_handler(self, request: Request):
    response = VoiceResponse()
    stream = Stream(url=f"{request.host}")
    if condition == True:
        start = Start()
        start.append(stream)
        pause = Pause(length=10)
        response.append(start)
        response.append(pause)
    else:
        start = Connect()
        start.append(stream)
        response.append(start)

    return str(response), 200, "text/xml"
```